# is a null node a valid Binary Search Tree

Tags: binary-search-tree

Is an empty Binary Tree a valid Binary Search Tree

I mean is tree has root == null and there is no left and right child then is it a binary search tree

will we consider an empty binary tree as a valid binary search tree .

Comment: What if you have a binary search tree with 5 nodes, and then you remove the 5 nodes one by one from it. Does it suddenly stop being a binary search tree?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an empty tree is a possible binary search tree. Just like we have empty arrays, empty queues, empty stacks, empty sets, empty dictionaries, so also we have empty binary search trees.

The Wikipedia article on [Binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Insertion) includes pseudo code for inserting values into a binary search tree, and it deals with the case where the binary search tree is empty and the first value is inserted into it. Also the [delete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Deletion) operation deals with the case where the binary search tree becomes empty.

One caveat is that *if* your data structure only knows the concept of a "node" and not of a "tree", an empty tree will have to be represented with a `null` value, and so it cannot be distinguished from `null` itself.

The solution is that you should define a proper container class that can represent the tree, and which has `root` as an *attribute*. That way you always have a proper tree instance (which is not `null`), but whose `root` attribute could be `null`.